# Speed of comparing structs using derive(Eq) versus derive(Serialize)

Tags: performance, rust

I was curious about how much faster it is to call `Eq::eq` to compare two large vectors, versus serializing both vectors to a string and comparing the output strings.

I've done a basic speed-test here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=73fc1cc61873fa70566eb7b2bf0793f9

The results, in release-mode, for a vector of 100 thousand simple structs:

1. Comparing by `Eq::eq(x, y)`: 20ms
2. Comparing by `serde_json::to_value(x) == serde_json::to_value(y)`: 172ms
3. Comparing by `serde_json::to_string(x) == serde_json::to_string(y)`: 34ms

These results surprise me a bit; I did not expect that serializing all the way to a string would be nearly as fast as the derived implementation of `Eq::eq`.

Is my speed-test flawed in some way? If not, what would explain why there is not a speed advantage to the `Eq::eq(x, y)` approach, given that it seems like it should have a lot less work to do?

Comment: I don't know rust, so might be irrelevant, but if `vec.clone` copies the vectors, you might want to take that out of the timing (or avoid the cloning if that's possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `vec.clone()`

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=8f5badd5e2d1b7258eda6b384acd9205

The results after passing references:
`Times. 1:1 2:127 3:39`

Comment: Good point, thanks! (a bit embarrassed I didn't notice that...)

Comment: For future reference: I [modified the speed-test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=acd4f2d045a663bf18a34bb0505ad844) to match my use-case better (I have two owned vectors, and just want to compare the "new" with the "old", prior to returning the new one), and this increases `test1` (Eq::eq) from ~1ms to ~3ms, yet *decreases* `test3` (serialization) from ~40ms to ~17ms. The `Eq::eq` is still several times faster, but I guess the move operation becomes significant enough to blur the differences some. (though not sure why serialization actually got faster)

Comment: Actually, my modification above was flawed; it ignored the fact that versions 2 and 3 allow you to "store the calculated Value or String" directly, for comparison during the next iteration, whereas version 1 requires that you make a clone in order to store the old value. The [fixed speed-test](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=4f133a58e5f04fed5fe5642913e995ad) (for my specific use-case) now has almost exactly the same speed between `serde_json::to_string` and `clone`+`Eq::eq`. (apologies for the extra comments, but wanted to clarify for future reference)